# reset combo box after unselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to reset childcombo box after disabled by parent combo. Child combo box is being disabled when i am selecting `select option` in parent combo box. After populating child combo box if i am selecting `select` option in parent combo, child combo is going to be disabled but how to reset child combo at this time that is child combo will also show `please select` option? What i need to add in javascript?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function(){
var arrVal = ["RS", "MN", "KL"];
 $("#parentcombo").change(function(){
 var valToCheck = String($(this).val());

 if ( jQuery.inArray(valToCheck,arrVal) == -1 )
 {
 $("#childcombo").attr("disabled", "true"); 
 }
 else
{ 
         $("#childcombo").removeAttr ( "disabled" );    
}        
});
});
});     
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<select id="parentcombo">
<option value="_">select</option>
<option value="RS">RS</option>
<option value="MN">MN</option>
<option value="KL">KL</option>
</select>

<select id="childcombo" disabled="true">
<option value="_">please select</option>
<option value="somevalue">somevalue</option>
<option value="somevalue1">somevalue1</option>
<option value="somevalue2">somevalue2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$('#childcombo').val("_")` to select `"please select"` option in child combo box.

If you want to select any option in `select` element use `val()` method and pass the option `value` to it, it will select that `option`.

In your case since you want to select `"please select"` option in child combo box we used its value `"_"` to pass to `val()` method.

Alternative way using pure javascript is to set `selectedIndex` property of the select element.

```
$('#childcombo')[0].selectedIndex = 0;//option index to set selected
```

Comment: Damn, beat me by 30 seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#childcombo").val("_");
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
else
{ 
    $("#childcombo").removeAttr ( "disabled" );    
    $("#childcombo").val('_'); /// <=====
}
```